# Erro ao Chamar função Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@fornecedores.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>
```

Na mesma página tenho o seguinte script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".details").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $("#modal").load("Detalhes?id=" + id, function () {
            $("modal").modal('show');
        })
    });
})
```

Quando dou o Click olha a mensagem que aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse exemplo peguei nesse link:
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3686/aspnet-mvc-e-bootstrap-exibindo-views-modais.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Para funcionar você precisa dar o include do `js` do twitter bootstrap 3.

Como está usando Asp .Net MVC, pode usar `bundle`, no arquivo `BundleConfig.cs` você configura assim:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"));
```

Depois no seu html você chama os bundles criados assim:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
```

Lembrando que os arquivos de `css` e `js` do `bootstrap` deverão estar nas pastas corretas, você pode colocá-los manualmente ou utilizar o `NuGet`.

Ou pode usar assim:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-Sk3nkD6mLTMOF0EOpNtsIry+s1CsaqQC1rVLTAy+0yc= sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: *Includes* assim não são recomendados, sobretudo porque o ASP.NET MVC tem o próprio mecanismo de minificação. É melhor instalar por NuGet e usar o `BundleConfig` para minificar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, me ajudou muito...

Tenho mais um problema relacionado a essa pergunta.

Tenho uma <div> que carrega o meu modal.

Quando dou _get_ minha div está vazia, porém quando ocorre o evento click a <div> recebe as informações da modal, porém não aparece na tela.

Comment: Melhorei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

O console diz que a função não foi definida porque modal() não é uma função nativa do Jquery, e sim do Bootstrap.js.

Logo, se você não tem o arquivo do bootstrap.js sendo chamado uma tag script,a função não vai existir.

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você dar este exemplo em código. O que acha?

Comment: O script feito pelo J.C. está provavelmente correto (pelo menos em relação à chamada do modal está), o problema é que ele estava usando uma função da biblioteca bootstrap.js sem antes tê-la incluso em sua página. Ele poderia ter feito isso a chamando de uma CDN, como a maxcdn  (`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"`), de um arquivo local (ex: /js/bootstrap.min.js) ou por um gerenciador de pacotes (bower, NuGet, etc)

Comment: Não, não, você não entendeu. Eu te sugeri melhorar a resposta. Não comentar aqui. Coloque um exemplo usando a `@section Scripts {}`, e tal.

Answer (score 0):

inclua o arquivo do bootstrap, sem instanciá-lo ele n reconhece, caso haja conflito por causa de outras bibliotecas, não esqueça de usar o noConflict() do jQuery.

Comment: Perdão, mas não entendi...

Comment: se mesmo que vc tenha incluído os devidos arquivos .js, e caso exista outros, teste o noConflict do jQuery, pode ser, talvez, algum conflito :
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/